# A special matrix "norm" based on quadrants

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We define the activation of the vector $x$ as
$$d:=D_x(A \cdot x)= \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } (A \cdot x)_i \leq 0 \\ 1 \text{ if } (A \cdot x)_i > 0 \end{cases}$$
i.e. the activation $d$ is a $n$-dimensional vector with zero entries if the $i$-th entry of $A \cdot x$ is smaller than one and one entries else. The activation region is just the indicator of the quadrant in which $A \cdot x$ lives. We define $M(A)=\{d_1,...,d_N\}$ as the set of all activations reached by $A$. There are in general $2^n$ different activation vectors. I.e. $N \leq 2^H$.

---

1. My first question is just whether these type of objects are already studied somewhere?
2. Secondly, given two matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a random acvitvation vector $d=(0,1,1,...,0)$ where $diag(d)$ is the matrix with $d$ as diagonal and set $W:= A \cdot diag(d) \cdot B$.

My question is the following: What is
$$N=|M(W)|$$ in this case?
I.e. how many of the $2^H$ activation regions are reached by $W$ for the given $d$? I am especially interested how $d$ influences $N$.

---

E.g. choosing $d$ to be the zero vector, only one activation is reached. Eigenspaces also play a special role in this question since $D_x$ is the same for all $x$ in an eigenspace.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $d_i$?

Comment: No., it should just be an indicator. But thanks, I edited the question to avoid confusion.